# How do I setup ASP.NET Identity to use my own connection string? I have two different options

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I am doing a project in MVC5 EF 5 and have read a million tutorials and have come to a sudden wall.

I have my connection string that allows me to use Database fist when using  Identity, and when I have to make a scaffolded Item that allows me to do CRUD, I have to switch it back to the auto created connection string.

So my question is, what can i do to get just one string to work, i cant find any documentation on what MVC5/EF is looking for when the connString is called.

here are the two string.

```
<!--<add name="TextronEntities" connectionString="Data Source=LEMN-476W-IT; initial catalog=Textron; integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
<add name="TextronEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TextronDBConnection.csdl|res://*/Models.TextronDBConnection.ssdl|res://*/Models.TextronDBConnection.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LEMN-476W-IT;initial catalog=Textron;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

the top one is the one that lets me log in and register new users, where the bottom one is the one that lets me do CRUD.

I comment one out to login and the other to use CRUD testing.

This inst a production project but might soon be and i would like to understand everything to the best of my knowledge.